# sp_senddb_mail mail remaining unsent

Tags: sql-server

My SQL Server services (`SQLSERVER` and `SQLAGENT`) were running with account `Domain\Account1` (for very long days). We were getting email notifications regularly.

Yesterday, I changed the service account for both the SQLSERVER and SQLAGENT to `Domain\Account2`. The services were restarted.

I have not received the expected emails so far. I checked the mails are in unsent state.

```
Select * from msdb.[dbo].[sysmail_unsentitems]
```

I added `Domain\Account2` (full control as Domail\Account1 was having) to the path of `DatabaseMail.exe`. Still no result.

What are the other things I need to check?

I am using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: what does mail error log table say ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM msdb..sysmail_log`, no log after the new account change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long investigation, I learned few things and fixed the issue.

The `DatabaseMail.exe` gets executed from SQL Server service is through member of an **Administrator group**. My account `Domain\Account2` was member of Administrative group but still it was failing.

Because, the service was not restarted after adding `Domain\Account2` to Administrator group (although I restarted after changing `Domain\Account1` to `Domain\Account2` in SQL Server Service)

Comment: restarting the service fixed it for us. There was nothing in the logs that gave us any indication of an error.

Answer (score 0):

After a long to check sysmail_log for Database mail:All mails have Unsent status .
I have execute below procedure and my issue has been resolved.
Procedure Name: sp_sysmail_activate

You can find this procedure in below script.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\ [Instance]\MSSQL\Install\sysdbupg.sql